# What does \? mean in a regular expression?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

The following command is used to search for a 7-digit phone number:

```
grep "[[:digit:]]\{3\}[ -]\?[[:digit:]]\{4\}" file
```

What does `\?` stand for?

Answer (score 23):

It's like `?` in many other regular expression engines, and means "match zero or one of whatever came before it".

In your example, the `\?` is applied to the `[ -]`, meaning it tries to match a space or a minus, but that the space or minus is optional.

So any of these will match:

```
555 1234
555-1234
5551234
```

---

The reason it's written as `\?` rather than `?` is for backwards compatibility.

The original version of `grep` used a different type of regular expression called a "basic regular expression" where `?` just meant a literal question mark.

So that GNU grep could have the zero or one functionality, they added it, but had to use the `\?` syntax so that scripts that used `?` still worked as expected.

Note that grep has an `-E` option which makes it use the more common type of regular expression, called "extended regular expressions".

`man 1 grep`:

```
   -E, --extended-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression
          (ERE, see below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)

   -G, --basic-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as a basic regular expression (BRE, see below).
          This is the default.
```

...

```
Repetition
    A regular expression may be followed by one of several repetition operators:
    ?      The preceding item is optional and matched at most once.
```

...

```
    grep understands three different versions of regular expression syntax:
    “basic,” “extended” and “perl.”
```

...

```
Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
    In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and )
    lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions
    \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).
```

---

Further info:

- `grep -E` option and `egrep`
- [GNU grep - Basic vs Extended](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html#Basic-vs-Extended)
- [Regexp Syntax Summary](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2002/06/regexp.html)
- [Regular Expression - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)
- [Why do some regex commands have opposite intepretations of '\' with various characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7600/why-do-some-regex-commands-have-opposite-intepretations-of-with-various-chara)

Comment: The `egrep` command is equivalent to `grep -E`.  For versions other than GNU grep, `grep` might or might not accept the `-E` option, and `egrep` might be a separate program.

Comment: @KeithThompson, `grep -E` is the official POSIX way. `egrep` was deprecated in susv2 (1997) and removed in susv3 (2001) from the POSIX and Unix specs.

Comment: `\?` is a GNUism though.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, the exact syntax of regular expressions varies slightly between different programs: grep regexes aren't exactly the same as sed regexes, which aren't exactly the same as Emacs regexes, which aren't exactly the same as C++ regexes, and so on. To make matters worse, even a "standard" tool like grep can vary slightly between different Unix-like operating systems.

In a regex, some characters have special meaning (such as the square brackets in your example), and revert to their normal meaning as literal characters when you "escape" them by putting a backslash in front of them (so a literal bracket would be written as \[). Others work the other way around, and only take on special meaning when escaped (e.g. plain n is just a letter, but \n is a line feed). And these, again, can vary between regex implementations.

In most regex implementations, a question mark means that the previous item is optional, while an escaped question mark (\?) is a literal question mark. But in a few dialects, it's the other way around. Your example could make sense either way around, but I suspect you have one of the dialects where ? is a literal and \? is the optional symbol. So your regex probably means "three digits, optionally followed by a space or dash, followed by four digits".

(Another clue can be seen in constructs like \{3\}, which is clearly intended to mean "exactly 3 of the previous item". In most regex dialects this would be written {3}, and \{ would be a literal brace.)

Answer (score 6):

This is a quick summary of information that's already contained in the other answers.

In `grep`, `?` matches a literal question-mark character, and `\?` denotes zero or one occurrence of whatever precedes it.  So in the example in your question, `[ -]\?` matches either a space, or a hyphen, or nothing.

In `egrep` or `grep -E`, it's the other way around; `\?` matches a literal question mark, and `?` denotes zero or one occurrence.

This applies to GNU grep; the details for non-GNU grep implementations may differ slightly.  In particular, `grep` and `egrep` were historically two separate programs, and I don't think old `grep`s had the `-E` option.  POSIX does specify `grep -E`, but (I was surprised to discover) doesn't mention `egrep`.